# Following a link to a php page doesn't work while the current page is being processed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages: `Home.php` and `Dashboard.php`.  The links to the pages appear as **Home** and **Dashboard** using an anchor tag rather than `javascript/jquery`.

When I click on **Dashboard** an ajax query is fired which starts fetching data from the server to display on the current page, however, during this time if I click on **Home** it does not take me to `Home.php` page until the page completely loads and the processing of the **Dashboard** page is finished.

I want to be able to follow the link without waiting for processing to complete. Can anyone please help me with this, what could be the issue.

Comment: Share your code?

Comment: Maybe caused by session locking?

Comment: Like @Rishi asck share your code, if you don't, the only thing we can do is suppose!

Comment: If both the links are anchor tag and you are not using javascript/jQuery, then why are you calling ajax?

Comment: Clarify description

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!!!**
I didn't get time to respond to your replies.  After doing some research work on PHP functions and my issue I found that it was because of Session Locking which is one of the solutions given by **frz3993**. Sorry, I didn't see that else I would have solved it the same day.

To rephrase my Question:
If we have a page 1.php which in turn is calling another page 2.php and this 2.php is using session variable across its without closing its use will result in session locking. The best way is to start a session and store the required session in a variable and release the session by calling **session_write_close()**. If a session is locked you won't be able to click and redirect to any other page which uses session.

I hope I have made myself clear this time.